# Axios POST status 400 bad request

Tags: httprequest, axios, http-status-code-400

I am trying to make a POST request to the spotify web api. I am using this piece of code for doing so:

```
axios.post(ACCESS_URL, {
    "grant_type": 'authorization_code',
    "code": code,
    "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI
},
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from(CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET).toString("base64"),
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
    })
```

In the snippet above `code` is the users authorization code and everything else are server constants. The problem is that I am getting the following error when I am performing the request:

```
 error: 'unsupported_grant_type',
        error_description: 'grant_type must be client_credentials, authorization_code or refresh_token'
```

As you can see, the grant type that I am sending in the request body is one of the 3 specified grant types, but I am stil getting status 400 and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance since I am sure it's a silly question with an easy answer, but I just don't see it

Comment: is your ACCESS_URL on the same domain as your script? if no, do you have CORS enabled for the ACCESS_URL?

Comment: No, it's not on my domain. The ACCESS_URL is the spotify web api.

Answer (score 0):

See [Unsupported grant type error when requesting access_token on Spotify API with Meteor HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159288/unsupported-grant-type-error-when-requesting-access-token-on-spotify-api-with-me) for a similar problem.

Spotify expects the grant_type in the query string parameters, not in the post request body. Actually the configuration in the above question/answer looks pretty similar to the axios config. Simply wrap your first three parameters into a `params` object:

```
axios.post(ACCESS_URL, {
 params: {
    "grant_type": 'authorization_code',
    "code": code,
    "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI
  },
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from(CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET).toString("base64"),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})
```

Comment: By doing so I am now getting a 415 response code

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to encode the data using `querystring` like this:

```js
return axios.post(ACCESS_URL,querystring.stringify({
        "grant_type": 'authorization_code',
        "code": code,
        "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI
    }),
    {headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from(CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET).toString("base64"),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}
)
```

Thanks everyone for the help