# Spotify Web API can not get access token

Tags: php, laravel, spotify, guzzle

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Basic '. base64_encode(env('CLIENT_ID').':'.env('CLIENT_SECRET')),
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ])->post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', [
            'code' => trim($code),
            'redirect_uri' => env('REDIRECT_URI'),
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        ]);
print_r($response->json());
```

This return code:

> [error] => unsupported_grant_type [error_description] => grant_type parameter is missing
> when i want to get access token.

Comment: How can we expand upon a fairly clear response from the API?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - at full response i am getting 400 bad gateway error

Comment: It appears this person has had the same issue w/ 400 bad gateway. Try moving your data params:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159288/unsupported-grant-type-error-when-requesting-access-token-on-spotify-api-with-me

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem by using Guzzle Client library instead of Http facade of laravel.And I sent options as form_params.Thanks for your replies.

```html
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', [
            'headers' => $headers,
            'form_params' => $options
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, if you expect to use Http client and set the Content-type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" just call the asForm() method, like described in Laravel Http documentation (source: https://laravel.com/docs/master/http-client#authentication).

```
$response = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode(env('CLIENT_ID') . ':' . env('CLIENT_SECRET'))])
            ->asForm()
            ->post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', [
                'code' => trim($code),
                'redirect_uri' => env('REDIRECT_URI'),
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
            ]);
```